# Tastypie filter by minimum value

Tags: backbone.js, tastypie

I have a Django-tastypie resource that represents a banner and has a field called impression that I increment whenever the banner appears on the site.

```
class BannerResource(ModelResource):

    owner = fields.ForeignKey('advertisment.api.AdvertiserResource', 'owner', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Banner.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'banner'
        authorization = Authorization()
```

I would like to get the banner that has the minimum impression, in the official documentation there is nothing like

```
filtering = {'impressions': ('min',)}
```

I'm using BackboneJS in the front end and I could get all the banners with Backbone collection and do the filtering with JavaScript but I'm looking for a quicker way to do it.
Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to retrieve banners with number of impressions greater than `X` you need to things. For one you need to define possible filtering operations on your resource like so (given your model has `impressions` field):

```
class BannerResource(ModelResource):

    owner = fields.ForeignKey('advertisment.api.AdvertiserResource', 'owner', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Banner.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'banner'
        authorization = Authorization()

        filtering = { 'impressions' : ALL }
```

for available options take a look at [Tastypie's documentation on filtering](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#basic-filtering).

Then if you made the following request:

```
GET http://<your_host>/v1/banners?impressions__gte=X
```

you should get what you need.